# How to properly reset all grub/boot settings?

Tags: boot, grub2, 11.10, plymouth, tty

Several symptoms:

- No splash screen, just a console
- No TTYs available (CTRL+ALT+F1 etc..), just random coloured bars

A while ago, I've used a tutorial to fix Plymouth bootsplash resolution and changed settings I don't quite recall now. What is the proper way to reinstall and reset Plymouth and/or GRUB settings to see if removing my modifications will fix the boot to some acceptable level?

NB: I've updated to 11.10-beta hoping it would fix the problem, but this originally happened on 11.04

**Edit**: I think the tutorial I followed is [this one](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml) but I'm not 100% sure. Also, I think the things mentioned in the tutorial are not the only ones I've changed, since I've tried to fix this when it first happened, so I may have messed up other stuff too. This is why I'm looking for a "reset all" solution.

Comment: Can you provide us a link to the tutorial you followed to edit the Plymouth bootsplash resolution?

Comment: @nitstorm: I've updated the question ;)

Comment: Cool :) Did you try undoing each of the steps in that tutorial?

Comment: @nitstorm: Hm, I have to say I didn't.. I figured the update from 10.10 to 11.04 caused the problem so I didn't think my modifications are a problem. Now, I think I might try it... :)

Comment: You probably made some changes to your `/etc/default/grub` file, so if you are at a loss, give us the contents of it.

Comment: @nitstorm: Well, it seems like the "undo everything" worked. I got the splash back, it's low-res, huge and ugly but I somehow just love it :) Also, the TTYs are back. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can give you some props? :)

Comment: @dr Hannibal Lecter: Oh awesome! Will post my comment as an answer. Feel free to edit the answer as you wish with the steps you took :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try undoing each of the steps in [that tutorial](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml)?

Like, *(Note: This is just an undoing of whatever that was done in that tutorial)*

1. `sudo apt-get remove v86d`
2. editing the `/etc/default/grub` file and

   1. changing the line 9 which would now read     `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset       video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"` back to    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   2. and line 18 which would now read - `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024` back    to    `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024`.

3. `gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and remove the last line reading `uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap`

4. Remove the line that reads `FRAMEBUFFER=y` in the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` file

5. Then run `sudo update-grub2`

6. Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

7. Then `reboot`