# Grub doesn't work anymore after some iffy changes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've recently been having issue with my apt package installer (more details here: [I can't use apt install anymore after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411757/i-cant-use-apt-install-anymore-after-upgrade)). The issue stemmed from my grub, and I fixed it by essentially destroying my grub. This might not have been as much of an issue if I could have fixed it before restarting, but now I'm stuck in windows without being able to access my ubuntu partition.

When starting up, I get a black screen at the moment where I'm supposed to get the grub. After a while it semi reboots and goes into BIOS. I checked, and ubuntu is first in the boot order.

Is there any way I can fix the grub from windows or setup a different grub from windows?

Comment: You can boot into a live USB, chroot into your existing Ubuntu install, and repair/reinstall grub from there, see https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/1083397